# How to print my arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class golfScores{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    // array to hold  
  //loop and array building
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] scores = new int [10];
    System.out.println("Please enter the golf Scores :");
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
      scores[i] = sc.nextInt();
     }
    System.out.println("The Scores you enterd are: " +scores[]);

  }
}
```

it wont print my array. I get syntax error, insert ". class" to complete Expression

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores))`

Comment: Thank you that was simpler than I thought lmao.

Comment: You have to write another loop to print that array.
    `for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("The Scores you enterd are: " + scores[i]);
                }`